# Java Script not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have login box on a site, its suposed to slide, but it doesn't really work and I can't figure it out why, here's the code:

```
<div style="float:right; width:640px; font-size:10px;">
<div style="float:right; margin:5px;" align="right">

Pentru a va conecta apasati <a onclick="ShowHide(); return false;" href="#">aici</a><br/>
<a href="/register.php">Inscriere utilizator nou</a>
</div>
<div id="loginbox" class="div_login_box">
<form action="/login.php" method="post" name="loginform">
<table width="420" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>E-Mail:</td>
    <td><input name="email" id="email" type="text" size="15" /></td>
    <td>Cod:</td>
    <td><input name="password" id="password" type="password" size="15" /></td>
    <td><input style="border:none" name="submit" type="image" src="/images/ok.png" border="0" value="Ok" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the live example:

http://dev.eurodiet.ro/

Comment: Can you add your javascript code

Comment: On your site, jquery and many scripts fail to load. See the js console

Comment: As well you have not defined the showhide function. Tested your script

Comment: just a typo :D ("scripts" instead of "Scripts") ... 3 days of "debugging" and this was the problem, I now go to shoot myself. sayonora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't ask us to debug your websites / scripts without checking basic things by yourself.

This is console output from Chrome (`F12` or `CTRL+SHIFT+i`)

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://dev.eurodiet.ro/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://dev.eurodiet.ro/Scripts/swfobject_modified.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://dev.eurodiet.ro/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://dev.eurodiet.ro/Scripts/eurodiet_scripts.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: swfobject is not defined dev.eurodiet.ro:147
Uncaught ReferenceError: swfobject is not defined dev.eurodiet.ro:196
```

Comment: sorry for that, the thing I didn't even knew where to look, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: funny enough, it was because my scripts folder was "scripts" instead of "Scripts" a small typo that would have took me eons to "debug".

Java Script and ActionScript are CASE SENSITIVE! :)

Comment: if this was the case, then Apache was (an it is) case sensitive, as there are most Unix filesystems.
Either way, I am glad you managed to fix the problem.